# Use ng2-charts with Nathan Walker Angular2 NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I started a new project today using Nathan Walker advanced seed for angular 2 and nativescript. I need to use ng2-charts or any other charts library. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, It's not possible because nativescript use the native view and native api, and ng2-chart use an webview.
Of course, nativescript have the webview api https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/web-view , but I think it's for rendering html (from raw or url)
So, your solution is to find a native chart works with nativescript
https://github.com/markosko/nativescript-charts
or the official one (paid) http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/Chart/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

[Official NativeScript UI](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/introduction) components are not paid anymore and are the first choice of components when meet your needs.

It also has chars for Angular-Nativescript combo [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/Chart/overview)

Easy way to play with these UI components before you start coding for it is the demo app available [here](https://www.nativescript.org/ui-for-nativescript#GeneralContent_C047_Col00).